# Can't login to Gmail via Mail on iOS

Tags: gmail, ios

I am having trouble accessing my Gmail account via Mail on my iPad. It keeps saying my username or password is incorrect when it's not. I have that rotten two-step authentication turned off and this is still happening. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the credentials are correct by logging in on another device?

Answer (score 1):

If you do have two-step verification enabled you can just go to the [App passwords](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) page to generate an app-specific password, although you shouldn't need it on recent versions of iOS / OS X.

If you are sure that two-step verification is turned off I suggest to verify your password. And if you're 100% sure it's correct try changing your password, or if turned off recently turning two-step verification back on.